# Find all the prime numbers $p,q$ that satisfy both $ p\mid q+6$ and $q\mid p+7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Some observations:
$$\begin{cases}\begin{cases}q+6=pk\Rightarrow q=pk-6\\
p+7=ql\Rightarrow p+7=(pk-6)l\Rightarrow p-pkl=-6l-7\Rightarrow p(kl-1)=6l+7\end{cases}
\begin{cases}p+7=ql\Rightarrow p=ql-7\\
q+6=pk\Rightarrow q+6=(ql-7)k\Rightarrow q-qlk=-7k-6\Rightarrow q(kl-1)=7k+6\end{cases}\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}p\mid 6l+7\\ q\mid 7k+6\end{cases}$$

So $p$ gives a remainder $1$ when divided by $6$ and $q$ gives a remainer $6$ when divided by $7$. In other words:$$\begin{cases}p\equiv 1\pmod 6\\q\equiv 6\pmod 7\end{cases}$$
All this is probably not useful at all. I've simply written a few of my observations. So could anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: How about $p\le q+6$ and $q\le p+7$, which rearranges to $q-7\le p\le q+6$.  Further, unless they're both equalities, either $p\le \frac{q+6}{2}$ or $q\le \frac{p+7}{2}$.

Comment: @vadim123 how did you get the last bounds?

Comment: If $a|b$ then there is some integer $c$ such that $ac=b$.  Assume $a,b,c>0$.  If $c\neq 1$, then $c\ge 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the size of $p$ and $q$ is limited by the two conditions: $$p \mid q+6 \text{ and } q \mid p+7 \Rightarrow pq \mid (6p+7q+42)  \Rightarrow pq \leq (6p+7q+42)$$
Now you can show that $p,q\geq 16$ is a contradiction to the above inequality. So either $p \leq 13$ or $q \leq 13$. But as we have the two divisibility conditions, this also limits the other number (to $19$ in this example). So you find all solutions by testing numbers smaller than these bounds.

Hint: If you want to cross-check your result: I found exactly one tuple $(p,q)$ satisfying the properties.